# Number of recursive calls in gcd() function

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

Recently I have been given a `gcd()` function, written in C programming language which takes two arguments `n` and `m` and compute the GCD of these two numbers using recursion.I have been asked that "How many recursive calls are made by the function if `n>=m`?" Can any one provide the solution with explanation to my problem as I am unable to figure it out.
Here is the source code of the function :

```
int gcd(int n, int m)
{
  if (n%m==0)
    return m;
  else
    n=n%m;
  return gcd(m, n);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it on paper to see if you can find a pattern?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm. This will help you understand.

Comment: @Thomas Jager I have done it, but can't find any useful pattern.

Comment: I think an upper bound for the number of recursive calls (including the original call) when `n>=m` is given by `1 + log(m) / log(phi)`, where `phi` is the golden ratio `phi = (sqrt(5) + 1) / 2`. The lower bound (including the original call) is 1. When `n<m`, add  1 to the upper and lower bounds.

Comment: For an example of the worst case, try successive numbers from the Fibonnacci sequence for `m` and `n`.

Comment: @IanAbbott How you have derived the formula `1 + log(m) / log(phi)`?

Comment: It's easy enough to work out that consecutive Fibonacci sequence numbers are the worst case by working backwards from gcd(2,1). It is also known that the ratio between successive numbers in the Fibonacci sequence approaches phi the further along the sequence you go, so the sequence is approximately exponential with a base of phi. The `log(m) / log(phi)` calculates log to the base phi of `m`. The 1 is added for the initial call to `gcd`.

Comment: This question might be a better fit for [cs.se].

Answer (score 4):

[Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) gives #steps =

> T(a, b) = 1 + T(b, r<sub>0</sub>) = 2 + T(r<sub>0</sub>, r<sub>1</sub>) = … = N + T(r<sub>N - 2</sub>, r<sub>N - 1</sub>) = N + 1

where `a` and `b` are the inputs, and `r_i` the remainder. We used that `T(x, 0) = 0`

Running an example in paper would help you get a better grasp of the aforementioned equation:

> gcd(1071, 462) is calculated from the equivalent gcd(462, 1071 mod 462) = gcd(462, 147). The latter GCD is calculated from the gcd(147, 462 mod 147) = gcd(147, 21), which in turn is calculated from the gcd(21, 147 mod 21) = gcd(21, 0) = 21

So `a = 1071` and `b = 462`, and we have:

```
T(a, b) = 
1 + T(b, a % b)       = 1 + T(b, r_0)   =    (1)
2 + T(r_0, b % r_0)   = 2 + T(r_0, r_1) =
3 + T(r_1, r_0 % r_1) = 3 + T(r_1, r_2) =    (2)
3 + T(r_1, 0)                           =
3 + 0                                   =
3
```

which says that we needed to take 3 steps to compute gcd(1071, 462).

```
(1): notice that the 1 is the step already done before, i.e. T(a, b)
(2): r_2 is equal to 0 in this example
```

You could run a plethora of examples in paper, and see how this unfolds, and eventually you will be able to see the pattern, if you don't see it already.

---

Note: While @Ian'Abott's comments are also correct, I decided to present this approach, since it's more generic, and can be applied to any similar recursive method.